# Why we need to instantiate the class Snake and assign it to variable snake

Tags: python, class, oop, object

'''
This code is simply print the attribute in the class by the use of object
'''

```
class Snake:
    name = 'Python' # set an attribute 'name' of the class
    rn = 'java'

# instantiate the class Snake and assign it to variable snake 
snake = Snake()

# access the class attribute name inside the class Snake
print(snake.name)


# print the same thing directly calling the class attribute
print(Snake.name)
print(Snake.rn)
```

Comment: What?  What are you asking?

Comment: `Variable` name doesn't need to be same as `Class` name, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking for.

But if I understand you correctly you want to know what is the benefit of assigning the instantiated class to a variable.

Well if you have multiple instances of a class you might want to adress each object.
There is also something called polymorphism [see here more](https://python-intro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polymorphism.html).
Basicly it allows you to overload functions and variables of a class.

Here is a good blog entry about Object-oriented Programming (OOP) [What Is Object-Oriented Programming](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)

```
class Snake:
   name = 'Python'
   snake1 = Snake()
   snake2 = Snake()

   snake1.name = "Carl"
   snake2.name = "Hans"
   print(snake1.name)
   print(snake2.name)
   print(Snake.name)
   //Output 
   //Carl
   //Hans
   //Python
```